# After failing to post a chat message and correcting the cause, “retry” should actually retry, and succeed

Tags: bug, chat, login

Sometimes I get logged out of chat. No biggie, I just click on the “chat” link from a Q&A site where I'm logged in and it logs me back into chat.

I usually realized that I'm logged out because I try to post a message in a tab that I had open back when I was logged in, and I see the message “You must login to post - retry / cancel”.

[image: You must log in to post]

It would be nice if clicking “retry” tried to log me back in, but it doesn't. Never mind, I log into chat as described above. Now I'd like to actually post that message. I click “retry”.

[image: parsererror]

Now it's a  *parsererror*. I need to reload the tab before I can post anything.

I'd still like to post that message without having to retype it. I can copy-paste the displayed text, reload the tab, and post, but that doesn't preserve the markup. Since I haven't posted that message, there is no “edit” control. If I forget to copy-paste before reloading, the message is lost.

I'm tagging this one with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because the “retry” button doesn't seem to do anything useful (and because humans shouldn't see a “parsererror”), but this is mostly a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): when posting a message fails due to a temporary error (such as not being logged in), give me a way to retry posting my message (one that actually works, I mean).

I'm using Chrome stable 31.0.1650.57 under Linux. I'm sure I've seen that with older versions of Chrome, and I think (but I'm not 100% sure) on other platforms as well. Although I normally use the SE Chat Modifications extension, I made sure I could reproduce without it before posting this message.

Comment: Yet another of those silly users who expect UI elements to do what they suggest they'll do. End-users like you give me headaches!

Comment: Wish every end use I had was Gilles.

Comment: As a side note. you should actually be able to up-arrow to edit in that case, I think.

Comment: The UI should also probably respond more readily to the fact that you're logged out to begin with.

Comment: **+1** I once got an unexplained *parsererror* while trying to chat in the Tavern. Only reloading cleared it. I think that might be related somehow.